# No option of creating new file in centos 7 gui

Tags: centos, files, gui

I have recently installed centos 7 and was trying to create a new file through right click and selecting create a new file option as I have done in centos 6 but there is no option of create new file in Centos 7.I know I can use terminal for that but is there any way I can do it with the GUI.

Comment: Start an editor (like `emacs` or `gedit` or `kate`). Then `Save As...` the new file.

Comment: What GUI are you using, The default i.e. GNOME3?

Comment: And it also depends of the type of the file you want to create. For example, to create an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, a compiler like `gcc` and/or a linker is very often the best option.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know I can do that but why there is no option `new file` when I right click and also also I dint give any name so I dont think  it has something to do with extensns

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I am using the default one as I dint change any thing related to GUI during installation

Comment: So what? You can start an editor, and I actually recommend to start `emacs` at start of work time (so once a day at most)

Comment: What kind of file do you want to create? Text file? Image? It all depends on context.

Comment: are you serious, does centos lack this basic feature that i see in alll desktop os-es??

Comment: The notion of file on Linux and POSIX systems is quite different from what it is on other OSes.

Comment: @MatthewRock I want to create a text file but why it matters because I dint reached to that point yet.

Comment: @codegasmer Because there are numerous options of creating different files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it only gives you the option to create a file if there is a template in your Templates directory - `~/Templates/`.

If it's empty, create an empty text file in there called (for example) `Text Document`.

Also, confirm that `XDG_USER_DIRS` environment variable points to the above directory.  If not, change it in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

The (not-a-)bug report is [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687139).

Comment: thanks for the help  was hitting my head on the wall for hours to solve this

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on editing text file you want to create, you can also start with text editor. Let's take an `Emacs` for example:

1. Go to directory where you want to create file and name the file

   ```
   C-x C-f /path/to/file.txt
   ```
2. Press enter.
3. If directory did not exist, you have to create it:

   ```
   M-x make-directory
   ```
4. Press enter twice. Voila, you're in newly created file, ready to edit.

(C - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> M - <kbd>Alt</kbd>, M-x means "Press <kbd>x</kbd> while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>.")